# What's wrong with my AWK when coping with the last column?

Tags: linux, awk

I write a shell script to abstract data from a file named "POSCAR". It is produced in the win10 system. It looks like this:

```
System
1.0
       23.0000000000         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000        23.0000000000         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         0.0000000000        17.0000000000
    C    H
   24    7
Direct
```

The 6th and 7th rows are element symbols and number of atoms. I want to get a string = C24H7. So I wrote the script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$PWD
fin="POSCAR"
e_tot=`sed -n 6p $fin   |awk '{printf "%.1d", NF }'`
echo There are $e_tot columns.
ele=""
for ii in $(seq 1 1 $e_tot)
do
  echo $ii
  aa=`sed -n 6p $fin |awk -v ll=$ii '{printf "%s", $ll}'`
  mm=`sed -n 7p $fin |awk -v ll=$ii '{printf "%d", $ll}'`
  col=$aa$mm
  ele=$ele$col
done
```

The output is wield for the last column. I can get C24H, but the "7" is lost. Or it just be exported to the next row.
I thought it may be related to the last character of the row, which is produced by windows and not recognized by Linux, and which I don't know is what. 
BEGIN{FS="[ \n\t]+"} for awk does not work.
Where is wrong ?
THANK YOU...

Comment: A complex script which combines shell, Awk, and `sed` can very often be simplified drastically by doing it all in a single Awk script.

Comment: You are right~ @tripleee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'NR==6{a=$1;b=$2}NR==7{print a $1 b $2}' file
C24H7
```

Comment: Thanks for your simplification... But I think the problem is in my input file "POSCAR". Because both my code and your code work well for the output file "CONTCAR" after a Fortran-based software.

Comment: @smirkymonkey: Does your file use dos line endings? Run first `dos2unix yourfile` and try again

Comment: Thank you!!! `tr -d '\015' < POSCAR > POSCAR1
echo `awk 'NR==6{a=$1;b=$2}NR==7{print a $1 b $2}' POSCAR1 `` It finally woks. Thank you very much! I learned a lot!

Comment: @smirkymonkey: Well, that can be simplified as well: `tr -d '\015' < POSCAR | awk 'NR==6{a=$1;b=$2}NR==7{print a $1 b $2}'` :)

Comment: yes yes thank you! And I finally earned 15 reputations to upvote this answer :))